# Shuffle comma-separated list of values in one cell (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm wondering if anyone could give me a helping hand in shuffling a comma-separated list of values in one cell in Google sheets. My data looks like this:

```
peter, andrew, mike, michael, ..., thomas
```

I'd like to randomly shuffle this string for each row and I have about a thousand rows that all have one cell that looks like this.

Any formula or link to a page where I can get closer to a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far? Any search terms you've used?

Comment: Plenty – I've gotten as far as knowing how to shuffle string by letters, assigning a random number to each letter and then sorting and joining them back together. I know this is the right path but the formula is rather complex (since I'm not that familiar with G Sheets formulas) so I'm having a hard time applying this to my use case.

Comment: Can you please share a test sheet with data for your given scenario, results and formulas you used? It would really help us help you.

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with a formula based solution to this, but I know some of the experts will think of something...  I'll keep working at it though.

Comment: @sharkmountain great that you already tried out some solutions. Can you edit your question to include that? No need to write "edit", or "update", just integrate what you've tried in your answer.

Comment: Also as @marikamitsos states, it would be great to have some test data. Not as a screenshot, as then it needs retyping.

Answer (score 0):

### Draggable Single Formula

Here's a formula if you're ok with dragging a formula down:

```
=ArrayFormula(
    JOIN(
        ", ",
        Array_Constrain(
            SORT(
                TRANSPOSE(
                {
                    SPLIT(A1, ", ");
                    RANDARRAY(1,COUNTA(SPLIT(A1, ", ")))
                }),
                2,
            ),
            COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,", "))
            ,1
        )
    )
)
```

### Two ArrayFormulas

It may be possible to combine these two into one, so I may revisit this later.

1. Make sure you have three columns clear. I chose C as my start column.

```
=ArrayFormula(
    SORT(
    {
        ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
            SPLIT(
                TRANSPOSE(
                    SPLIT(
                        TEXTJOIN(
                            ",",
                            1,
                            (SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A))-1)&"|"&SPLIT(FILTER(A:A&", ",LEN(A:A)),", ")
                        ),
                        ","
                    )
                ),
                "|"
            ),
            COUNTA(
                SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,A:A),", ")
            ),
            2
        ),
        RANDARRAY(
            COUNTA(
                SPLIT(
                    TEXTJOIN(", ",1,A:A),
                    ", "
                )
            ),
            1
        )
    },1,1,3,1)
)
```

2. Final result.

```
=ArrayFormula(
    TRANSPOSE(
        SPLIT(
            REGEXREPLACE(
                TEXTJOIN(
                    ", ",
                    ,
                    UNIQUE(
                        TRANSPOSE(
                            IF(
                                TRANSPOSE(FILTER(C:C,LEN(C:C)))=FILTER(C:C,LEN(C:C)),
                                FILTER(D:D,LEN(D:D)),
                                ";"
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                ", (;, )+",
                ";"
            ),
            ";"
        )
    )
)
```

The tricky part was getting the "group concatenation" to work.

Comment: Just to point out, in case you or others weren't aware, that for @Calculuswhiz' first formula, Draggable Singleton, it does not actually have to be dragged down, provided an adjacent column has data going all the way down.  Once you have enter that (or any) formula in a cell, just double click on the tiny square symbol at the bottom right of that cell, the same place you would "grab" to drag down.  This will fill the cells all the way down with the equivalent formula.  Much easier than dragging down a thousand rows.